# Proc report including macro variables as a label

Tags: sas

I would like to create a large demographic table by each country.

Wondering if there is a way to create a table using 'by statement' and changing the first column name as per the country?

As there is an if condition in countries, so I was wondering to create the list of macro variables for all the country names but they can be between 15 to 25, would you let me know how this can be achieved?

Comment: What have you tried ? Have you looked at documentation or the many, many conference (SGF/SUGI) papers about `Proc REPORT` ? Yes, A `Proc REPORT` step can have a `BY` statement.  It can also have a `WHERE` statement to restrict which rows of data end up in the report. The columns in REPORT are those listed in the `COLUMN` statement.  Update your question with some sample data, tried code and any log messages.  Describe any output you get that is close but not exactly what you want.

Comment: If you have no clue how to deal with this type of problem, you can post at communities.sas.com where the requirements are less strict. As far as I know, the only way to do this is macro variables, but you can also use #byval/#byvar in several places so it may be possible.